# Read socket in PHP without continuous running script in iframe

Tags: javascript, php, performance, sockets, jquery

I am very new to socket connections, so any help here would be awesome. I've searched for a solution to this issue for the past several days and perhaps I'm not searching for the correct things.

I currently have a PHP script that I run continuously in an iframe triggered by a jQuery event that takes packets received from an external device, translates them and plugs them into a MYSQL database.  It's one-way communication; I don't have to write anything back to the socket.  My issue is that I don't want to run this PHP script continuously because I plan on running it from several domains at the same time for up to an hour at a time. I was told this would eat up my server's memory like crazy.

Here's the code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$socket = NULL;
$host = "012.345.678.910";
$port = 8080;
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush(true);
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP) or die("create():".socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)));
socket_set_nonblock($socket);
if (!socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)) {
    echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
    exit;
}
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Bind():".socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)));
$count = 0; 
while (TRUE){
    $count += 1;
    usleep(0.25 * 1000000); // 0.25 seconds
    $input = socket_read($socket,10000);
    if($count == 4){
        if(!$input){ 
            echo "<br>ERROR: ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
        }else{
            $input = trim($input);
                            // Here's where I translate and plug it into the database.
        }
        $count = 0;
    }
    if(ob_get_level()>0)
            ob_end_flush();
}
socket_close($socket);
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is there a way to run the script once per second, start to finish, and have it read the data that way instead of continuously running?  If so, how do I do it?
2. If not, how do I optimize the performance of this script so I can run several instances from several domains at the same time?

Comment: ditch the loop and call the script periodically, either via ajax or cronjob

Comment: Is it really that easy?  If so I am going to feel really stupid.  Does the data just sit in the socket till I go and retrieve it?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be work if I ditch the loop and call it every second from ajax.  It keeps returning "Resource temporarily unavailable".  Any ideas?

Comment: Upon further review the $input is actually FALSE, not "". So according to php.net there is an error somewhere, not just no data to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that meets my needs for Question number 1 above. I ended up changing the script to include a socket_select() call with a timeout of 0.25 seconds, and calling it once per second using AJAX.  Here's the new code in case it helps anyone:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$socket = NULL;
$host = "012.345.678.910";
$port = 8080;
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush(true);
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP) or die("create():".socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)));
socket_set_nonblock($socket);
if (!socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)) {
    echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
    exit;
}
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Bind():".socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)));
$read   = array($socket);
$write  = NULL;
$except = NULL;
$timeout = (0.25 * 1000000); // 0.25 seconds
$num_changed_sockets = socket_select($read, $write, $except, 0, $timeout);  
if ($num_changed_sockets === false){
    echo "ERROR----".socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
}else{
    $input = socket_read($socket,10000);
        // manipulate data
}
if(ob_get_level()>0)
    ob_end_flush();
socket_close($socket);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run PHP CLI scripts forever if you call gc_enable(1) combined with nohup or screen.

Comment: @Christian The PHP CLI SAPI default is to have no time limit.

Comment: @Christian absolutely, check http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php